# Is there a way to have Script Editor web parts or Content Editor web parts back inside sharepoint online modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, iframe, modern-pages, script-webpart

I am new to the sharepoint online modern pages world. Now i read a lot about it and decide to start using it instead of the classic web pages. now the SP modern pages provides some useful features and capabilities compared to the SP classic web pages. but at the same time modern pages lack some basic functionalities compared to classic web pages!!!. For example i can not do the following inside sharepoint online modern pages:-

1. i can not add an image with link !!
2. i can not add a custom javascript or custom HTML using script editor web part.

now what i need more is the ability to write custom JavaScripts inside modern pages, but i could not find a way to do so!! the only option i find, is to add the custom HTML and JavaScript inside a classic site page, and then reference this classic site page inside our modern page using the modern Embed web part which uses iframes..

**so my question is, can we have script editor web parts inside our modern site pages?**

Final point. i found this link :-

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/dev/samples/react-script-editor

but i did not understand how i can install it, to test its functionalities?.

second question i have. is if there are any drawbacks, if i write my custom JavaScript and custom html inside a classic site page using the standard script editor web part, and then reference the classic page inside our modern page using the Embed modern web part (which uses iframes)?? as currently this is the only option i find, to do my work.. something as follow to reference a classic page which have images with links:-
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To use React js script editor in modern pages you will have to:

Upload a spkg file of the solution you have shared in the apps catalog of your tenant. And then install the client side solution on the specific SharePoint site page. To understand the process to achieve this follow [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

My suggestion for you is invest some time to understand SPFx development. (adds much more value for our clients than classic SharePoint)

Comment: thanks for your reply. now i am trying to keep things simple in my case. i am building a home page for our intranet, where i want to add some images and provide links for them + add some web parts. this could have been a straight forward task, if the modern pages allow adding script editor webparts or allow adding images with links, which i was surprised the modern page does not support them. so now if i want to add the script editor webpart what do i need to do exactly? which file i need to upload inside the app catalog? and which file i need to install on our site collection?